# Matching the start and the end of a repeating-linear-gradient pattern in css

Tags: css, css-animations, linear-gradients

I created a bar (you can see in the snippet below) with infinite diagonal stripes using css' `repeating-linear-gradient` and i tried to create an animation, it should roll the stripes in horizontal direction.

Almost got it. The problem is in the start and the end of the background, the end of the stripes pattern don't match with the start, creating a broken pattern.

Is there a way to make css repeat the pattern outside of the drawing area, or other hack that could fix this problem?

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    black, black 10px,
    transparent 10px, transparent 20px);
  animation: pb-animation 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes pb-animation { 
  0% { background-position: 0px }
  100% { background-position: 100px }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
</div>
```

**PS:**
I know if I put a specific width in the div I will fix it, but this is not helps because this pattern should be used on generic loading bars (the width and height will be determined by the context of use).

Comment: The problem is with the image itself. I would recommend ensuring that both edges of the image match up, by cropping the image so that the edge is half-way through the black bar.

Comment: Quickest solution is to change the width of `.progress-bar`. The magic values are `width: 141px` and `background-position: 141px` at 100%.

Answer (score 1):

It's only a matter of finding the right angle and number :D
It work with below number of transparent.

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    black, black 10px,
    transparent 10px, transparent 14.1px);
  animation: pb-animation 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes pb-animation { 
  0% { background-position: 0px }
  100% { background-position: 100px }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
</div>
```